# Codeigniter enctype="multipart/form-data" not save photo properly

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

**Codeigniter** When i use **enctype="multipart/form-data"** in signup form photo not save in database but photo going to uploads folder. Then When i remove **enctype="multipart/form-data"** photo save in database but photo not coming uploads folder. If this is problem for the code, please do the full code. Because I'm not a good developer.

**View**

```
<form method="post" action="family_join" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="wizard">

    <h4 class="text-center mb-4 mt-4">Upload Photo</h4>
    <div class="form-group mt-3 mb-4">
        <div class="dropzone-wrapper">
            <div class="dropzone-desc">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></i>
                <p>Choose an image file or drag it here.</p>
            </div>
            <input type="file" name="photo" class="dropzone">
        </div>
    </div>

    <h4 class="text-center mb-4">Please enter the zipcode</h4>
    <div class="default-form contact-form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="zipcode" placeholder="Enter Zip Code" required>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

**Controller**

```
< ? php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
Class Family_Join extends CI_Controller {
    public
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load-> helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }
    public
    function index() {
        $this->form_validation-> set_rules('zipcode', 'Zipcode', 'required|min_length[4]');
        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
            $zipcode=$this->input->post('zipcode');
            $photo=$this->input->post('photo');
            $status = 1;
            $this->load->model('Family_Join_Model');

            $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->do_upload('photo');

            $this-> Family_Join_Model->insert($zipcode, $photo, $status);
        } else {
            $this->load->view('user/family_join', array('error' => ' '));
        }
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
< ? php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
Class Family_Join_Model extends CI_Model {

    public
    function insert($zipcode, $photo, $status) {
        $data = array(
            'zipcode' => $zipcode,
            'photo' => $photo,
            'isActive' => $status
        );
        $sql_query=$this->db->insert('tblfm', $data);
        if ($sql_query) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Registration successfull');
            redirect('user/family_join');
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Somthing went worng. Error!!');
            redirect('user/family_join');
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens because when you set enctype to multipart/form-data your input send to server as a binary file and a binary file can not be inserted in database.

For inserting file name into your database follow steps below.

1. Keep enctype=multipart/form-data (So your file will be uploaded to server)
2. replace this line :

   $this->Family_Join_Model->insert($zipcode, $photo, $status);

with these:

```
$upload_data = $this->upload->data(); 
$this->Family_Join_Model->insert($zipcode, $upload_data['file_name'], $status);
```

Answer (score 0):

Upload file first and get the file name from uploaded file data.

```
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if ($this->upload->do_upload('photo')) {
            $file_details = $this->upload->data();
            $photo = $file_details['file_name'];
        } else {
            $file_upload_msg = $this->upload->display_errors('<p>', '</p>');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->upload->do_upload('photo');
$upload_data = $this->upload->data();
$this->Family_Join_Model->insert($zipcode, $upload_data, $status);




**Model**

public
function insert($zipcode, $upload_data, $status) {
    $data = array(
        'zipcode' => $zipcode,
        'photo' => $upload_data['file_name'],
        'isActive' => $status
    );
    $sql_query=$this->db->insert('tblfm', $data);
    if ($sql_query) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Registration successfull');
        redirect('user/family_join');
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Somthing went worng. Error!!');
        redirect('user/family_join');
    }

}
```